# jQuery show/hide text field based on a dropdown selection value and a radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show/hide a hidden field based on a dropdown selection value **and** a radiobutton value.

Here's part of my code:

```
State of Issue: 
<select size="1" name="State_of_Issue" class="required" id="state">
<option>MA</option> 
<option>NH</option>
<option>NY</option>
</select>

Partnership:
<input type="radio" name="Partnership" value="Yes" class="required" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="Partnership" value="No" />No

<select name="Asset_Number" id="asset" style="display:none;">
                <option>Total Asset 100%</option>
                <option>Total Asset 50%</option>
                <option>Dollar for Dollar 100%</option>
                <option>Dollar for Dollar 50%</option>
            </select>

Script:
$('#state').change(function () {
   if ($(this).val() == "NY") {
     if ($('#partnership').val() == "Yes") {
        $('#asset').show();                        }
       }
       else {
           $('#asset').hide();    
          }
       });
```

I want to be show the hidden field "asset" when state = NY and when partnership = Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script. **UPDATED**

```
$('#state, input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    if ($('#state').val() == "NY") {
        if ($('#partnership').is(':checked')) {
            $('#asset').show();
        } else {
            $('#asset').hide();
        }
    } else {
        $('#asset').hide();
    }
});
```

And a fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/Tu7Ja/5/

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uSucE/16/)

```
$('#state, input[type="radio"]').change(checkState);

function checkState() {
    var state = $('select').val();
    var partnership = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();

    if ((state == "NY") && (partnership == "Yes")) {
        $('#asset').show();
    } else {
        $('#asset').hide();
    }
}
```